# How do I make a plot showing only parts of a function?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot parts of the function $y = \tanh(x\, y^2)$. I have been able to plot the complete function, but I want to see just some particular parts. I am a Mathematica beginner. I have attached an image of the function. I would like to have suggestions on how I can make the plot I want.

The part of the function I want to plot can be described as below;

if  $|x| < x_c$, then $x = 0$
if $|x| > x_c$, then $y = $ <upper branch of the bifurcation>

with $x_c = 2.016$.

[image]

Comment: I think you might be interested in `Piecewise`.

Comment: Yes, piecewise.

Comment: I mean, you might be interested in the [`Piecewise` command](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) in MMA. Take a look at the linked documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have tried it and I had an empty plot. This is the code I used                                                                                                          
Plot[Piecewise[{{y =0, x < 2.016}, {y =tanh(x y^2), x > 2.016}}], {x, -4, 4}]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 eq = y == Tanh[x y^2];
 yn[x_?NumericQ, xc_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[
   {{y /. FindRoot[eq, {y, Sign[x]}], Abs[x] > xc}}];
 Show[
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq, {x, -3.75, 4}, {y, -2.5, 2.5},
   ContourStyle -> LightBlue],
  Plot[yn[x, xc], {x, -3.75, 4},
   Exclusions -> {-xc, xc},
   PlotStyle -> Red]],
 {{xc, 2.016, Subscript["x", "c"]}, 1.7, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
xc = 2.016;
yc = y /. NSolve[y - Tanh[x*y^2] == 0 /. x -> xc, y, Reals] // Max;
ContourPlot[{If[Abs@y >= yc, y - Tanh[x*y^2]], 
  If[Abs@x <= xc, y] , y - Tanh[x*y^2]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2, 2},
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Red, Opacity[.2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Manipulate[
 yc = y /. NSolve[y - Tanh[x*y^2] == 0 /. x -> xc, y, Reals] // Max;
 ContourPlot[{If[Abs@y >= yc, y - Tanh[x*y^2]], If[Abs@x <= xc, y], 
   y - Tanh[x*y^2]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Red, Opacity[.2]}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {{xc, 2.016}, 2, 3}]`

Answer (score 1):

An approach based on post-processing `ContourPlot` output:

```
cp = ContourPlot[y == Tanh[x*y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> Gray];
```

Extract the coordinates of three contour lines:

```
{c1, c2, c3} = Cases[Normal[cp], Line[x_] :> x, All];
```

Use `` Internal`ListMin `` to define a function for identifying *top* and *bottom* branches and selecting coordinates that satisfy the threshold condition:

```
ClearAll[branch, clippedcontourstop, clippedcontoursbottom]

branch[side_: {"left" | "right", "bottom" | "top"}] := 
  Module[{s = side /. {"left" | "top" -> -1, "right" | "bottom" -> 1}}, 
    SortBy[First][s # & /@ Internal`ListMin[s # & /@ #]]] &;

clippedcontourstop[t_] := Prepend[Select[Abs[#[[1]]] <= t &] @ c1]@
  MapThread[Select[branch[{#, "top"}] @ #2, Abs[#[[1]]] >= t &] &, 
     {{"left", "right"}, {c2, c3}}]
```

Use with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Show[cp, Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], 
      MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], Line @ #} &]@ clippedcontourstop[t]}], 
    Axes -> True, PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"threshold = ", t}], 16]], 
  {{t, 1, "threshold"}, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Simple modification to get the *bottom* branches:

```
clippedcontoursbottom[t_] := Prepend[Select[Abs[#[[1]]] <= t &] @ c1] @
  MapThread[Select[branch[{#, "bottom"}] @ #2, Abs[#[[1]]] >= t &] &,
     {{"left", "right"}, {c2, c3}}]

Manipulate[Show[cp, Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], 
     MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], Line @ #} &] @ clippedcontoursbottom[t]}], 
   Axes -> True, PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"threshold = ", t}], 16]], 
{{t, 1, "threshold"}, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, control the threshold parameter using a `Locator`:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 0}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = {#[[1]], 0}) &], Dynamic @ Show[cp, 
   Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], 
      MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], Line @ #} &]@ 
         clippedcontourstop[pt[[1]]]}], 
     Axes -> True, PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"threshold = ", pt[[1]]}], 16]], 
  {{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]]
```

[image]